# How do I integrate hapi-fhir dependencies for a RESTful Client in a Grails project?

Tags: grails, dependency-management

I am having some trouble using a FhirContext object in a Grails project that I am working on in Eclipse. I intend to use code similar to that found at the top of this page:

http://jamesagnew.github.io/hapi-fhir/doc_rest_client.html

I am pretty sure that in order to do so, I need to add dependencies to my project and then import some libraries (I am also unsure exactly which libraries are necessary.)

I added the dependencies found at the following link by creating an maven POM file, pasting the dependencies into it, and adding a "pom true" line to my BuildConfig.groovy file.

http://jamesagnew.github.io/hapi-fhir/download.html

Still, I get errors when I include fhir libraries, and thus I am unable to use any FhirContext objects.

Comment: Why do you need to use a POM to include dependencies in your BuildConfig?

Answer (score 1):

On the google group ( [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hapi-fhir/qfuMD5b0YK0) ) it was suggested to use the following in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
 dependencies {
    // HAPI - FHIR
    compile 'ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-base:1.0'
    compile 'ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-structures-dstu2:1.0'

    // HAPI - FHIR Support
    compile 'org.jscience:jscience:4.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}
```